# Settings Menu is cut off from screen

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-15.04

I use a lot of language layouts on my computer, and its gotten to the point where I cannot add any more because the add keyboard layout screen in the Ubuntu settings goes off the screen so I can't select the more options button on the bottom.

How can I add more keyboard layouts (I don't actually need language system support, just the layout) via terminal? Are there files I can alter?